# MySQL IN Operator

Tags: sql, mysql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

http://pastebin.ca/1946913 
When i write "IN(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)" inside of  the procedure, i get correct result but when i add the id variable in the "IN", the results are incorrect. I made a function on mysql but its still not working, what can i do?

Comment: `id` is a string-y type; you can't just paste it there and expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings (broadly, variable values) don't interpolate in statements. `vKatID IN (id)` checks whether `vKatID` is equal to any of the values listed, which is only one: the value of `id`. You can create dynamic queries using [`PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to interpolate values:

```
set @query = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) AS toplam
                    FROM videolar
                    WHERE vTarih = CURDATE() AND vKatID IN (', id, ') AND vDurum = 1;') 
PREPARE bugun FROM @query;
EXECUTE bugun;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET( )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) rather than IN, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS toplam
FROM videolar
WHERE vTarih = CURDATE()
AND FIND_IN_SET( vKatID, id ) > 0
AND vDurum = 1
```

[Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html) have limitations - they can't have more than 64 members for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your id variables is a string (varchar) not an array (tuple in SQL) ie you are doing the this in (in java)

```
String id = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
```

you want

```
int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

So in your code

```
set id = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I cannot help you with the syntax for declaring id as I don't know. I would suggest to ensure the code is easily updated create a Table with just ids and then change your stored procedure to say

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS toplam
                        FROM videolar
                        WHERE vTarih = CURDATE() AND vKatID IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM idtable) AND vDurum = 1;
```

Hope this helps.